# Disable users from completing after a ~ in zsh

Tags: unix, shell, zsh

I like to use zsh's named directories feature to move about my file system quickly (e.g. so I can use ~src to switch to my source code directory).

I also like zsh's auto-completion features.

However, I work in an environment with a large number of users, so when I type "cd ~s" and hit tab, I get a huge number of possibilities completing to match all the users starting with s, instead of completing "~src".

I don't really care about completing usernames (except maybe my own, but I can live without that) in this environment. Is there a simple way to disable this, but still keep expanding named directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that's invoked after a `~` is called `_tilde` (because it's [declared with `compdef -tilde-`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_002dtilde_002d_002c-completion-context)). Define your own function:

```
_bangfalse_tilde () {
  # The standard _tilde function with users removed
  [[ -n "$compstate[quote]" ]] && return 1
  local expl suf ret=1
  if [[ "$SUFFIX" = */* ]]; then
    ISUFFIX="/${SUFFIX#*/}$ISUFFIX"
    SUFFIX="${SUFFIX%%/*}"
    suf=(-S '')
  else
    suf=(-qS/)
  fi
  _tags users named-directories directory-stack
  while _tags; do
    _requested named-directories expl 'named directory' compadd "$suf[@]" "$@" -k nameddirs && ret=0
    _requested directory-stack && _directory_stack "$suf[@]" && ret=0
  done
  (( ret )) || return 0
}
compdef _bangfalse_tilde -tilde-
```